# How do I rewrite a function using promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, filesystems

I'm new to node js. I have a task to find files by extension. I wrote a recursive function that searches for files by extension but cannot write the result to the array. said you need to rewrite the function using promises but I don’t know how to do it

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var path = require('path'); 
var pathSupplied = './';
var extFilter = 'js';
function extension(element) {
    var extName = path.extname(element);
    return extName === '.' + extFilter;
};

let result = []

let walk = function (dir) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
        list.forEach((item) => {
            let itemPath = path.join(dir, item);
            fs.stat(itemPath, (e, stats) => {
                if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                    walk(itemPath);
                } else {
                    if(extension(itemPath)){
                        console.log(itemPath)
                        result.push(itemPath)
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    })
}
walk(pathSupplied)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but `fs-extra` is an npm package that is basically fs, with promises. I use it all the time

Comment: @TKoL fs is basically fs with promises. We support promises in Node core for fs for a while now. `require('fs').promises`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum oh I had no idea! Does it have the same interface as fs-extra?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you'd make this a promise:

Where you'd normally have a callback:

```
fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) => {}
```

You can write your own function that looks something like this

```
function readdirP(dir) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, (err, list) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(list);
    })
  })
}
```

The npm package fs-extra has already done this for you.

Comment: how can i rewrite it with recursion?tell my please? withoud fs-extra

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below to use promises in this context, I'd recommend using promisify to convert callback based functions to ones that return promises. This saves you writing boilerplate code for each one:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const path = require('path');
const pathSupplied = './';
const extFilter = 'js';
const { promisify } = require('util');
const readdirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir);
const statPromise = promisify(fs.stat);

function extension(element) {
    var extName = path.extname(element);
    return extName === '.' + extFilter;
};

async function walk(dir, result = []) {
    let list = await readdirPromise(dir);
    for(let item of list) {
        let itemPath = path.join(dir, item);
        let stats = await statPromise(itemPath)
        if (stats.isDirectory()) {
            walk(itemPath, result);
        } else {
            if(extension(itemPath)){
                result.push(itemPath)
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

async function testWalk() {
    let result = await walk(pathSupplied)
    console.log("Result:", result);
}

testWalk();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this you can fix this without promise

```
const fs = require('fs');  

const folderPath = __filename.replace('index.js', '');

fs.readdir(folderPath, function (err, items) {
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] !== 'index.js') {
        var checkJsFile = items[i].match(/\.(js|jsx)$/) != null;
        if (checkJsFile) {
            var item = items[i].replace('.js', '');
            router.use(require('./' + item));
        }
    }
}
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: How does this help the OP either with the question of how to rewrite using promises or in the underlying one of collecting the list of paths into an array?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand why you are having this problem first,
You are calling an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)and then calling a console.log directly afterwards which will show output before the asyn function has completed

You can fix this one of two ways

1. Use a Promise or Callback to act on the result at a later time
2. Call the synchronous version of the method - https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options

   const results = fs.readdirSync(path)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below code for promises:

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var path = require('path'); 
var extFilter = 'js';

function extension(element) {
    var extName = path.extname(element);
    return extName === '.' + extFilter;
};

let pathList = [];

const readDirectory = dir => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    fs.readdir(dir, function (err, list) {
        if(err !== null){
            reject(err.message);
        }
        addPath(list,dir)
        .then(()=>{
            console.log(pathList);
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            reject(err.message);
        })
    });
});

const addPath = (list,dir) => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        let itemPath = path.join(dir, list[i]);
        fs.stat(itemPath, function (err, stats) {
            if(err !== null){
                reject(err);
            }
            else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
                readDirectory(itemPath);
            } else {
                if(extension(itemPath)){
                    pathList.push(itemPath);
                }
            }

            if(i === list.length-1){
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }
});

readDirectory("C://Users//Default//Desktop//New folder")
.then((items) =>{
    console.log(items.toString());
})
.catch((msg)=>{
    console.log(msg);
})
```